# Exponential and linear model in the same plot with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, regression

I want to plot a linear model and an exponential model in the same plot. I've tried this code

```
qplot(mpg,wt,data=mtcars)
+ stat_smooth(method="lm", se=FALSE)
+ stat_smooth(method="lm", formula=log(y)~x, se=FALSE)
```

and I get this plot
[image]

but I want the exponential model plotted in the original y scale, not in the log(y) scale.

Answer (score 0):

Your model is wrong, mpg will not vary as the log of weight. I think what you're looking for is:

```
stat_smooth(method='lm', formula=y~log(x), se=F)
```

I'd recommend adding `color="log"` and `color="linear"` in each smoother argument.

Comment: I now that the mpg not vary as the log of weigth. This is only an example. In my real data I makes sense to compare a linear model with an exponential and arise the same problem that in the question. So, I'm sorry, but your anwer is not valid for me. Tanks!

Comment: @Alf No, the problem is that you're taking the log of the dependent variable.

Comment: Yes, it's the easy way to fit an exponential model as a linear one. With the linear model I get log(y) and I have to apply the exponential to get y. To plot the exponential model I have to transform the y scale but I don't know how to use two different y scales in the same plot.